# Help Needed Showing that $\chi(\overline{G \times H}) \leq \chi(\overline{G}) \times \chi(\overline{H})$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Where $\chi(G)$ denotes the chromatic number, $\overline{G}$ the graph complement, and $\times$ the Cartesian Graph Product:

I need to show that  $(\forall G,H)( \chi(\overline{G \times H}) \leq \chi(\overline{G}) \cdot \chi(\overline{H}))$. This is a stepping stone in a proof I am writing, but I am having difficulty showing this.

It would be good if I could show that $\chi(\overline{G \times H}) \leq \chi(\overline{G}) \cdot \chi(\overline{H})$ is equivalent to $\chi(G \times H) \leq \chi(G) \cdot \chi(H)$, as it is a known result (Sabidussi 1957) that $\chi(G \times H) = \max \{ \chi(G),\chi(H)\}$. However, I am not sure if those two cases are really equivalent.

Specifically, I am not sure if it holds for all $G,H$ that $\overline{G} \times \overline{H} = \overline{G \times H}$.

Any help?

Comment: It's definitely not the case that $\overline{G} \times \overline{H} = \overline{G \times H}$ for all $G$ and $H$. For example $\overline{K_2} \times \overline{K_2}$ is the empty graph on 4 vertices, but $\overline{K_2 \times K_2} = \overline{C_4} = 2K_2$.

Comment: Isn't that also a counterexample ?  We have $\chi(\overline{K_2 \times K_2}) = \chi(2K_2) = 2 > \chi(\overline{K_2}) \times \chi(\overline{K_2}) = 1$

Comment: @manuellafond Good point. I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. To the questioner: Do your graphs have some other property not satisfied by this counterexample?

Comment: @manuellafond No, not quite. $K_2 \times K_2 = K_4$, not $2K_2$.

Comment: Ah, then maybe you are using a different product.  I (and Perry Iverson I think) was referring to the Cartesian product as stated here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs.  If that's not what it is, maybe you could provide the definition of the product you are using.

Comment: @manuellafond I'm also using the Cartesian Product. Please double-check your counterexample.

Comment: @Newb The wikipedia link manuellafond provided shows as the first example that $K_2 \times K_2 = C_4$, so $\overline{K_2 \times K_2} = 2K_2$.

Comment: @PerryIverson The wikipedia link is mistaken. Please verify it yourself. In a Cartesian Graph Product, two vertices are adjacent: $(v_1,w_1) \sim (v_2,w_2)$ if and only if ($v_1\sim v_2$ or $v_1 = v_2$) and ($w_1\sim w_2$ or $w_1 = w_2$)

Comment: Newb: no, your definition of adjacency in the Cartesian graph product is mistaken. Once again, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs

Comment: @Newb The definition you gave is for the strong product, not the Cartesian product: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs

Answer (score 1):

The OP probably means the tensor product.
The only 'categorical' product for graphs is the tensor product.
That is why most people reserve "$\times$" for the tensor product.
The cartesian product is commonly indicated with "$\square$".
In both the cartesian product and the tensor product the vertex set is the cartesian product of the individual vertex sets (which may have caused the confusion), but adjacencies are defined differently.

In $\overline{G\times H}$ (complement of tensor product) adjacency is defined by
$(g,h)\sim(g',h')$ if and only of $g\nsim g'$ or $h\nsim h'$.
Now let $c$ be a proper coloring of $\overline{G}$ and $d$ a proper coloring of $\overline{H}$.
Then $c\times d:(g,h)\mapsto(c(g),d(h))$ is a proper coloring of $\overline{G\times H}$
with $\chi(\overline{G})\times\chi(\overline{H})$ colors.

Indeed: if
$(g,h)\sim(g',h')$
then
$g\nsim g'$ or $h\nsim h'$, so
$g\sim g'$ in $\overline{G}$ or $h\sim h'$ in $\overline{H}$,
which means that either $c(g)$ and $c(g')$ are different, or $d(h)$ and $d(h')$ are different.